# Short story where humans are stronger than all other aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm sure I found this on this site but can't for the life of me find the answer again.

I'm looking for a science fiction story that starts off on an alien spaceship. There is a human that was abducted and is now dealing with alien bureaucracy. While he is dealing with this another alien attacks the station.

The human manages to shrug off two blasts from a weapon that would kill other aliens and then proceeds to rip limbs off the attacker and kill it. This shocks the other aliens as it turns out that humans are far stronger than any of them.

I think it then moves to a point where the solar system is blockaded and the original bureaucrat tries to have this undone by working with the 'grays'.

The reason that humans are stronger is due to them evolving on a 'death world'.

Comment: A very similar story, though not based on Earth, (ie if you liked that you'll like this) is Deathworld by Harry Harrison.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld

Comment: If you like the concept then there are parallels with Alan Dean Foster's Damned series also, starting with "A Call to Arms"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is [The Kevin Jenkins Experience](https://deathworlders.com/books/deathworlders/chapter-00-kevin-jenkins-experience/), a web-fiction that later formed the basis for what would become the [Jenkinsverse](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheJenkinsverse), on opensource fictional world.

- **He deals with an alien bureaucracy**

  > I gave this some consideration, and scrapped the form. He was quite
  >   correct and that status made properly navigating him through the
  >   immigration paperwork impossible. The recording would just have to do.
  >   Jenkins nodded, and our implants eventually decided that he meant that
  >   a prediction had come true. “You can see why the administration on
  >   station 442 kicked me out.” he said. “I’m a bureaucratic anomaly. The
  >   whole system is far too rigid to accommodate me and mine.”
- **He's revealed to come from a "*deathworld*"**

  > I ripped the data from the storage and attached it to the recording.
  >   True to his word, a full survey of the “human” homeworld revealed that
  >   it was indeed category twelve—a deathworld. Hostile, vicious and
  >   forever primordial.
- **He takes multiple shots and (largely) shrugs them off.**

  > “Unarmed, you single-handedly defeated three of the most feared aliens
  >   in known space, and you tell us you are neither a trained warrior nor
  >   a physically exceptional specimen of your kind. The security footage
  >   records you being shot seven times by heavy pulse gun fire and you
  >   have fully healed in less than three-times-eight diurnals,” I said.
  >   “Many officers have suggested to me that you are a security threat, on
  >   the grounds that if you decided to go on a violent rampage, there
  >   would be little that could stop you.”

Comment: If looking for more content in this general genre (and not just that specific universe), try Googling [humans are space orcs] - there is a surprisingly large volume of it.